# How to print out admin form in Drupal

Tags: 6, forms, users

I can print out user login form with:

```
print drupal_get_form('user_login');
```

How can I print out admin login form ?

Edit: Drupal 6

Comment: There's only one user login form in Drupal, you can use it for both admins and normal users to login

Comment: Thanks, But how can I redirect it to Admin Panel instead of user profile?

Comment: There are a bunch of different ways, probably the easiest would be to use [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination)